# There are 39 red balls, 59 blue balls, and 71 white balls in a box. In how many different ways can 98 balls be drawn out of the box?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $39$ red balls, $59$ blue balls, and $71$ white balls. Balls of the same colour aren't distinguishable. How many different ways of drawing out $98$ balls are there?

Is there a systematical approach to this rather than writing out all options?

/////
**Edit:**
Thank you all. The solution is $2022$.

The equation $R + B + W = 98$ has $\binom{100}{2}$ solutions. If we define set $A_1$ as set of all solutions to the quations where $R$ is at least $40$, set $A_2$ as set of all solutions where $B$ is at least $60$, and $A_3$ as set of all solutions where $W$ is at least $72$.

Then by deducting the cardinalities of sets $A_1, A_2, A_3$ we get:

$$\binom{100}{2}-\binom{60}{2}-\binom{40}{2}-\binom{28}{2}= 2022$$

Comment: Have you tried using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, what would the sets represent?

Comment: I suggest:  Suppose $k$ red balls are drawn, what's the least number of blue you must have?  Then sum.

Comment: Let $r, b, w$ be, respectively, the number of red, blue, and white balls. Then $r + b + w = 98$, where $r, b, w$ are non-negative integers.  You can find the number of solutions to that equation in the non-negative integers using [Theorem 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) on the linked page.  You can then have to subtract those cases with at least $40$ red balls or at least $60$ blue balls or at least $72$ white balls.

Comment: What exactly does different mean here? Does the order of drawing matter or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number of ways to 98 balls is equivalent to number of non-negative integral solutions to $$x+y+z=98$$ where $x \leq 39, y \leq 59, z \leq 71$.

which is simply coefficient of $t^{98}$ in $$(1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^{39})(1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^{59})(1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^{71})$$

simplify it, $(1-t^{40})(1-t^{60})(1-t^{72})/(1-t)^{3}$

$(1-t)^{-3} = 1+3t+6t^2+10t^3+\ldots$ (using negative binomial formula)

coefficient of $t^{98}$ in $(1-t^{40}-t^{60}-t^{72})(1+3t+6t^2+10t^3+\ldots)$ (note some of the terms I've omitted cause they're not going to affect coefficient of $t^{98}$)

So collect coefficient of $t^{98}, t^{58}, t^{38}, t^{26}$ from the second term (with sign) $= 4950 - 1770 - 780 - 378 = 2022$

Hopefully that is the answer

Answer (score 4):

We can pick 0 to 39 red and 0 to 59 blue balls. We must draw at least 27 of these, and then the number of white balls is fixed.

There are 40 x 60 = 2,400 ways to draw red and blue balls. We cannot draw zero red and 0 to 26 blue balls (27 choices), 1 red and 0 to 25 blue (26 choices) and so on; the number of combinations not allowed is the sum of integer from 1 to 27 which is 27 x 28 / 2 = 378, for a total of 2,022 ways.